# Data Integration with SQL Server Based Data and Google Analytics into Amazon Web Services data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, google-analytics, data-warehouse, data-integration

I have customer data related to bookings on SQL server, I also have Google Analytics data related to customer activity on their site. How is the best way to connect these in a data warehouse as there is no unique key to be able to join on? I am looking to be able to query this information and need information both from SQL server and Google Analytics within the same query.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: If there's no key to join on, how are you going to associate the data? Perhaps you can associate the data at a higher level (location, age, gender) rather than trying to match individual people

Comment: So for example, on the Bookings database we are looking to see how many people visited the particular page with a particular destination on the visited particular page value would come from GA.

Comment: By destination do you mean holiday destination? If you want to correlate the data you might need to summarise up to a common context like holiday destination and compare at that level.

Comment: Ok, so you recommend creating the joins on holiday destination and maybe an additional field such as Airport Origin or something along those lines?

Comment: It's driven by your available data but most importantly what your end user wants. If they don't know what they want (which his quite common) then it's up to you to find valid connections in the data. Certainly your comment sounds valid